# Call stored procedure with user defined parameter

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Is it possible to call Procedure A with parameter B which is User defined table type?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE A
(
    @MyTable B READONLY
)
AS
BEGIN
   SELECT * FROM C;
END

CREATE TYPE B AS TABLE 
(
   ID int, 
   PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)
```

EF-6 is version I use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To execute stored procedure you can use [`SqlQuery<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696545%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) and to pass [table-valued parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you can use [`DataTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("ID");
dt.Rows.Add(new object[]{ 1 });
dt.Rows.Add(new object[]{ 2 });
dt.Rows.Add(new object[]{ 3 });

var sqlParam = new SqlParameter("MyTable", dt){ TypeName = "B" };
var query = db.Database.SqlQuery<CModel>("A @MyTable", sqlParam);
var cmodels = query.ToList();
```

Comment: yes, it works, you solved my problem. For others, who need more informations: http://www.deliveron.com/blog/post/Table-Valued-Parameters-with-Entity-Framework.aspx